# Properties of IWebElement are not visible in VisualStudio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

I use Selenium WebDriver C# and PageFactory (PageObject) pattern to create automated tests. I develop them in Visual Studio 2013.

Before the latest version of Webdriver (now I use 2.47.0) it worked well but now I face the next problem: I can not view properties of my web elements.

Here is how I create and initialize an element:

```
public class MyPageObj : DriverCover
{
        public MyPageObj(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
        {
            //'Driver' is a EventFiringWebDriver (IWebDriver) from parent class
            PageFactory.InitElements(Driver, this);
        }

        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "#internal")]
        private IWebElement _myElement;
}
```

When I run tests and at a breakpoint I want to watch properties of _myElement I see only non-public members: http://prntscr.com/8o075p

If I don't use PageFactory and find elements using Driver.FindElement(By.How()) method it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Well as I found in this commit https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/689276b5e39c414edccf8a1bd11d71fd81b5fad4 were made some changes and that's why my problem is not a bug and won't be fixed(